# Achieving erase/restore drawing on UIImage in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, drawing, core-graphics

I'm trying to make a simple image eraser tool, where the user can erase and restore as drawing into an image, just like in this image:

[image]

After many attempts and testing, I have achieved the sufficient "erase" functionality with the following code on the UI side:

```
// Drawing code - on user touch
// `currentPath` is a `UIBezierPath` property of the containing class.
guard let image = pickedImage else { return }
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.frame.size, false, 0)
if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
    mainImageView.layer.render(in: context)
    context.addPath(currentPath.cgPath)
    context.setBlendMode(.clear)
    context.setLineWidth(translatedBrushWidth)
    context.setLineCap(.round)
    context.setLineJoin(.round)
    context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.clear.cgColor)
    context.strokePath()

    let capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    imageView.image = capturedImage
}

UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

And upon user touch-up I am applying a scale transform to `currentPath` to render the image with the cutout part in full size to preserve UI performance.

What I'm trying to figure out now is how to approach the "restore" functionality. Essentially, the user should draw on the erased parts to reveal the original image.
I've tried looking at `CGContextClipToMask` but I'm not sure how to approach the implementation.

I've also looked at other approaches to achieving this "erase/restore" effect before rendering the actual images, such as masking a `CAShapeLayer` over the image but also in this approach restoring becomes a problem.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, as well as alternative approaches to erase and restore with a path on the UI-level and rendering level.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I would recommend adding a CALayer to your image's layer as a mask.

You can either make the mask layer a `CAShapeLayer` and draw geometric shapes into it, or use a simple `CALayer` as a mask, where the `contents` property of the mask layer is a `CGImage`. You'd then draw opaque pixels into the mask to reveal the image contents, or transparent pixels to "erase" the corresponding image pixels.

This approach is hardware accelerated and quite fast.

Handling undo/redo of eraser functions would require you to collect changes to your mask layer as well as the previous state of the mask.

### Edit:

I created [a small demo app on Github](https://github.com/DuncanMC/MaskableImageView.git) that shows how to use a CGImage as a mask on an image view

Here is the ReadMe file from that project:

---

### MaskableImageView

This project demonstrates how to use a `CALayer` to mask a `UIView`.

It defines a custom subclass of UIImageView, `MaskableView`.

The `MaskableView` class has a property `maskLayer` that contains a CALayer.

`MaskableView` defines a `didSet` method on its `bounds` property so that when the view's bounds change, it resizes the mask layer to match the size of the image view.

The `MaskableView`  has a method `installSampleMask` which builds an image the same size as the image view, mostly filled with opaque black, but with a small rectangle in the center filled with black at an alpha of 0.7. The translucent center rectangle causes the image view to become partly transparent and show the view underneath.

The demo app installs a couple of subviews into the `MaskableView`, a sample image of Scampers, one of my dogs, and a UILabel. It also installs an image of a checkerboard under the `MaskableView`  so that you can see the translucent parts more easily.

The `MaskableView` has properties `circleRadius`, `maskDrawingAlpha`, and `drawingAction` that it uses to let the user erase/un-erase the image by tapping on the view to update the mask.

The `MaskableView` attaches a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to itself, with an action of `gestureRecognizerUpdate`. The `gestureRecognizerUpdate` method takes the tap/drag location from the gesture recognizer and uses it to draw a circle onto the image mask that either decreases the image mask's alpha (to partly erase pixels) or increase the image mask's alpha (to make those pixels more opaque.)

The `MaskableView`'s mask drawing is crude, and only meant for demonstration purposes. It draws a series of discrete circles intstead of rendering a path into the mask based on the user's drag gesture. A better solution would be to connect the points from the gesture recognizer and use them to render a smoothed curve into the mask.

The app's screen looks like this:

[image]

### Edit #2:

If you want to export the resulting image to a file that preserves the transparency, you can convert the CGImage to a UIImage (Using the `init(cgImage:)` initializer) and then use the UIImage function

```
func pngData() -> Data?
```

to convert the image to PNG data. That function returns nil if it is unable to convert the image to PNG data.

If it succeeds, you can then save the data to a file with a `.png` extension.

I updated the sample project to include the ability to save the resulting image to disk.

First I added an `image` computed property to the MaskableView. That looks like this:

```
    public var image: UIImage? {
        guard let renderer = renderer else { return nil}
        let result = renderer.image {
            context in

            return layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
        }
        return result
    }
```

Then I added a save button to the view controller that fetches the image from the `MaskableView` and saves it to the app's Documents directory:

```
    @IBAction func handleSaveButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("In handleSaveButton")
        if let image = maskableView.image,
           let pngData = image.pngData(){
            print(image.description)
            let imageURL = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("image.png", isDirectory: false)
            do {
                try pngData.write(to: imageURL)
                print("Wrote png to \(imageURL.path)")
            }
            catch {
                print("Error writing file to \(imageURL.path)")
            }
        }
    }
```

You could also save the image to the user's camera roll. It's been a while since I've done that so I'd have to dig up the steps for that.

Comment: Hey Duncan, thank you for the answer. Could you give an example of what you mean by drawing opaque or transparent pixels?

Comment: @Eilon did you see the example project I added? That demonstrates what I am talking about (Opaque pixels have an alpha value of 1.0, and transparent pixels have an alpha value of 0.0. Pixels with a value between 0.0 and 1.0 are partly transparent.

Comment: Does anyone know how to convert the final result to a PNG? or JPEG?

Comment: The point of the project is to make an image view partially transparent (to have an alpha channel.) JPEG images cannot include an alpha channel, so saving the image to a JPEG would defeat the whole purpose. Joaquin, you want to output an image with alpha channel to a PNG?

Comment: Hey @DuncanC. I’m looking for a way to export the final image. The format can be PNG. I’m creating an app where you can erase part of the image and send it through email.  What would be the best way to export the image to PNG? Thanks!

Comment: @JoaquinPereira I added some notes on how to save the resulting image as a PNG at the end of my answer, under the **Edit:** header.

Comment: And I just updated the sample project to add a save button that saves the resulting image as a png to the app's Documents directory.